Climbing down a ~6' drop in the attic
I'm trying to climb down from a 2nd floor attic to the top of a high ceiling on the first floor.  By my estimates, its about a 6' drop.
I've attached a 2x4 to 2 rafters via 6 3" decking screws.  It feels sturdy.
I've hung a rope fire escape ladder rated for 2000 lbs. It's looped back over itself as shown in the top-right diagram on the Amazon listing. Two sturdy karabiners with a threaded lock prevents the clasp from opening.
My goal is to drop down, drill through the top plate to run a CAT5e wire (seen in the foreground).  I plan on bringing enough lumber to add blocking to the stud wall so that I can climb back up without using the rope ladder (if necessary).
If I fall, its a 12-18' foot drop down to the first floor.
I'm not sure if I'm trying to talk myself into or out of this.
Any thoughts on how I can make this safer?  Should I use bigger lumber?  Different screws?  Try to install hangers?  Span more rafters?



Quite sure decking screws are not rated for that.  They are made to hold wood down onto joists.  You probably want structural screws or a real ladder on a base of thick wood.

What's your question? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Edited to add a clearer question.  I'll go buy some structural screws and see if I can change the way this is attached.
Should I consider hangers?  It's a bit hard to work up here -- it would be kind of tricky to get the fit just right for hangers.

Most attic floors/ceiling if below have wood joists running across them.  Dropping/laying down carefully some 1/2 or 3/4 inch plywood(big enough to hold a ladder) will work with less work, less chance of something pulling out.  Or take a local ten year old and tie a rope around them and drop them down with the drill.  Always keep yourself safe.

Me, I'd have drilled a hole in the ceiling, from below, then poked through a piece of stiff wire with a large loop bent into the end, then nipped back up to the attic and gone fishing. That way (a) you're less likely to have to repair a man (other types of people are available) shaped hole in the ceiling and (b) the wire exits the room below in exactly the right place. I haven't attempted to make this an answer because there is probably some obvious reason you haven't approached the task this way.

@HighPerformanceMark heck, if you just push a piece of wire through the hole with some fishing line attached, the fishing goes easy with a magnet.  Of course, this assumes access to the bottom of the top plate—we have no idea where the OP is running the wire below here.

This isn't where the run stops.  Ultimately, I have to make it through an inside corner as well and then out through a brick fascia.  I am running PoE to a doorbell.  There are other reasons I want to get down into that space -- other projects that I have in mind where I ultimately need to get down that ledge.

Wow, I've never been in an attic quite like that one. Interesting -- you could make yourself a little secret room in there or something.
Anyway, yes, you could do a little better than what's pictured. The screws are arranged such that they depend on pull-out strength and tensile yield (stretching to breaking) of the screws. With a different approach to the bracketry you could cause the fasteners to be in a shear stress instead; I think many fasteners would be stronger that way.
There's a board visible through the insulation, set back maybe a foot from the edge of the upper level. You could ensure that's nailed down to the 2x4s below it, then attach your rope ladder there. Those nails aren't going to shear. The top plate of the unseen wall supporting the upper level should have no trouble supporting the forces of your rope ladder looping down/around it.

Thanks!  I had considered that, but was worried it might be a bit tricky going down a ladder there.  There's not much to hold on to, and you have balance on a pretty thin strip of wood as you try to transfer your weight onto the rope ladder hanging from there.  That being said, I could maybe add some 2x4s so that it's easier to go up and down that ladder.
I'll give it a shot and see if I can run the ladder from that position, as it would undoubtedly be stronger.

I managed to put some structural screws exactly as advised, and got down there safely.  Plenty sturdy with a 2x4 and 3" structural screws.  Thanks for the advice!
